# Filtering out UTF-8 punctuations and symbols from a String

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

What is the best and most efficient way to filter out all UTF-8 punctuation characters and symbols like ✀ ✁ ✂ ✃ ✄ ✅ ✆ ✇ ✈ etc from a String. Simply filtering out all characters that are not in a-z, A-Z and 0-9 is not an option, because I want to keep letters from other languages (ą, ę, ó etc.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about dots, comas, quotes? Should they be also filtered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\p{L}` to match all unicode letters. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] test = {"asdEWR1", "ąęóöòæûùÜ", "sd,", "✀","✁","✂","✃","✄","✅","✆","✇","✈"};
    for (String s : test)
        System.out.println(s + " => " + s.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}^\\d]", ""));
}
```

outputs:

```
asdEWR1 => asdEWR1
ąęóöòæûùÜ => ąęóöòæûùÜ
sd, => sd
✀ => 
✁ => 
✂ => 
✃ => 
✄ => 
✅ => 
✆ => 
✇ => 
✈ =>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the combinations of unicode [binary classifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc):

```
String fixed = value.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to remove accents first.

```
public static String onlyASCII(String s) {
    // Decompose any ŝ into s and combining-^.
    String s2 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    // Removee all non-ASCII
    return s2.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\u007E\\pL]", "");
}
```

For Greek and such `\\pL` letters.

Answer (score 0):

The term "punctuation" is rather vague. The `Character` class provides a [getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28int%29) method that maps to at least some of the defined [character categories](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#general_category) in the Unicode spec, so this is probably the best place to start.

I'd recommend also apply "positive" logic (eg, all characters and digits) rather than "negative" logic (no punctuation), because the test is likely to be much simpler.